# this code can keep the thread-salfe?(IOS)

Tags: ios, multithreading

here is the class:

```
@interface PhotoManager ()
    @property (nonatomic,strong,readonly) NSMutableArray *photosArray;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_queue_t concurrentPhotoQueue;
@end
```

i want to make the property photosArray (setter and getter) thread-safe:

```
- (void)addPhoto:(Photo *)photo
{
    if (photo) {
        dispatch_barrier_async(self.concurrentPhotoQueue, ^{ 
            [_photosArray addObject:photo];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                //Notification to update the UI; 
            });
        });
    }
}
```

and the getter method:

```
 - (NSArray *)photos
    {
        __block NSArray *array;
        dispatch_sync(self.concurrentPhotoQueue, ^{
            array = [NSArray arrayWithArray:_photosArray];
        });
        return array;
    }
```

but the apple develop document said: "As an optimization, this function invokes the block on the current thread when possible."
so the barrier in the concurrentPhotoQueue may not block other thread if the concurrentPhotoQueue queue is not the "current queue",such as the getter may call in main thread. In other word the getter method still is not thread-safe if one thread set the mutableArray and other thread read the mutableArray simultaneously.

Is my opinion right? if so, how can i modify the getter method?
Note: i quote these codes from a blog.

Comment: This deadlocks easily when thread limit is reached (64) `for (int i = 0; i< 1000; i++)
    {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(){
            [photomanager addPhoto: photo];
            [photomanager photos];
        });
    }`

Comment: can you tell me why?

Comment: If you kill the app it generates the crash report with message `Dispatch Thread Soft Limit Reached: 64 (too many dispatch threads blocked in synchronous operations)`. It seems that gcd creates a thread for every dispatch_sync on concurrent queue. Sorry but I don't have better explanation why this is happening and how to avoid it.

Comment: i think it is the `for` loop cause the problem,because each loop will submit a task to the concurrentPhotoQueue asynchronously,but this method `dispatch_barrier_async` make only one task be executing every time on concurrentPhotoQueue,so there are many threads(either dispatch by dispatch_get_global_queue or concurrentPhotoQueue) blocked by `dispatch_barrier_async` in concurrentPhotoQueue.

Answer (score 0):

Optimizations usually jump in when they don't break the default behaviour.

The getter is probably executed on main thread when no other thread is adding photos. Now if a thread suddenly enters the `addPhotos` method while the `photos` getter is running on main thread -as an optimization choice-, the barrier call may internally know that the queue it should refer to is now the main queue instead of `concurrentPhotoQueue`. Sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: i have test,result is that they all run on different thread provid by the concurrentPhotoQueue include the dispatch_barrier_sync() method。thanks